# Is there any reason not to use resource.getInputStream()?

Tags: java, spring, file-io

Is it ever favorable to create a `FileInputStream`, like this:

```
InputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(resource.getFile());
```

instead of using the `InputStream` created by the resource, like this:

```
InputStream resourceInputStream = resource.getInputStream();
```

The resource is an `org.springframework.core.io.Resource`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is the input stream, then there is no reason not to use it. The point of `getFile` is getting access to the file in ways other than opening a `FileInputStream` on it, such as reading attributes, moving, deleting, opening it through NIO instead of classic IO, etc.

Answer (score 3):

A resource does not always come from a File. It may come from a network resource or be dynamically generated by the class loader. If you do that you may be fine 99% of the time, but you could have trouble in specific unexpected situations.

As a general rule it's better not to make assumptions about the concrete implementation of anything.

By using `resource.getFile()` your making the assumption that the resource comes from a file.

Comment: Yes, I clearly see the benefits of using `resource.getInputStream()`, but is it ever favorable to **not** use it?

Comment: @DavidPärsson sorry I understood your question backward. I don't see any reason to create a FileInputStream from the file if you just need an InputStream.